# enqueue_script with filemtime javascript not working

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

Hey guys so I'm trying to enqueue a javascript with filemtime but every time I do it the custom js script I wrote doesn't seem to enqueue.

```
function add_js_scripts(){
   wp_register_script('lib',
      get_template_directory_uri().'/js/lib.js', 
      array(), 
      filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/js/lib.js'), 
      null, 
     'all'
   );

   wp_enqueue_script('lib');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','add_js_scripts');
```

The problem is now the lib.js file isnt showing up at all on the website. There are no php errors and if i remove the `filemtime` argument it shows up. Ive been version controlling it for development purposes.

Can someone tell me firstly if there is a better way to enqueue the script and if there is a way to enqueue it correctly with filemtime.

Also note i enqueued a style sheet successfully this way:

```
function add_css_scripts() {

    wp_register_style( 'style', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/style/style.css', 
        array(), 
        filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/style/style.css'), 
        null, 
        'all'
    ); 

    wp_enqueue_style('style');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_css_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that sometimes for some reason certain scripts dont seem to enqueue when you register the script then enqueue it when using filemtime in the parameter:

```
function add_js_scripts(){
wp_register_script('lib',
get_template_directory_uri().'/js/lib.js', 
array(),
filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/js/lib.js'), 
true); 
wp_enqueue_script('lib');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','add_js_scripts');
```

To solve this you can try and enqueue the script in one sub function like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('lib',
get_template_directory_uri().'/js/lib.js', array(),
filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/js/lib.js'), 
true);
```

This seemed to solve the problem of the script not enqueueing for me. I jsut wanna thank
Chinmoy Kumar Paul for guiding me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

**wp_register_script()** function is accepting the 5 parameters. You are passing the 6 parameter. So replace the

```
wp_register_script(
    'lib',
    get_template_directory_uri().'/js/lib.js', 
    array(), 
    filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/js/lib.js'), 
    null, 
    'all'
);
```

WITH

```
wp_register_script(
    'lib',
    get_template_directory_uri().'/js/lib.js', 
    array(), 
    filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/js/lib.js'), 
    true
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to work. The lib.js file doesnt enqueue at all if I dont include the `null` parameter.

Comment: I made mistake. last parameter would be **true**.

Comment: ok ill try this

Comment: if you add **true**, your JS file will add at footer (before the closing </body> tag). If you add **false** or nothing, JS will add to <head> tag.

Comment: Ok that didnt seem to work either.

Comment: `wp_register_script('lib',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/lib.js', array(),filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/js/lib.js'), true); `

Comment: Are you checked at footer? Is it not there?

Comment: No not in the footer when i use the `true` parameter

Comment: then it will go to **head** tag. Double check your JS path.

Comment: Unfortunately its not in the footer or head section using either `true` or `false` parameter

Comment: Enable debug mode and check the error log. There should be something if **filemtime()** is not getting the correct file path

Comment: I have, when i use: `wp_register_script('lib',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/lib.js', array(),filemtime(get_template_directory()_uri . '/js/lib.js'), true); ` in the filemtime parameter it says stat:failed

Comment: Ok it seems to be appearing in the head parameter now. Even though I added `true` to the parameter. Im gonna try with true and false

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your guidance helped me find the right answer. I just enqueued the script in one line and it seemed to fix it.

Comment: welcome @ZaydBhyat . Glad to help you.